# How do I set an integer column to null while updating the model object?

Tags: postgresql, rest, go, go-gorm

Suppose I have model class as follows

```
type Catalog struct {
    Title            string    `gorm:"column:title" json:"title"`
    Description      string    `gorm:"column:description" json:"description"`
    FeaturedMediumID uint      `gorm:"column:featured_medium_id" json:"featured_medium_id" sql:"DEFAULT:NULL"`
    FeaturedMedium   *Medium   `gorm:"foreignkey:featured_medium_id;association_foreignkey:id"  json:"featured_medium"`
    PublishedDate    time.Time `gorm:"column:published_date" json:"published_date"`
    Products         []Product `gorm:"many2many:catalog_product;" json:"products"`
}
```

Now when I POST to create object at that time the value of FeaturedMediumID is set to NULL in database if I pass 0 in request body. But after that if I update it to some value and then again want to unset the value than it does not allow.

I can set it to NULL by following query

```
DB.Model(catalog).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"featured_medium_id": nil}).First(&catalog).Error
```

But I want to do it directly in `.Updates()` query. Is there any way to do that? If I set it to 0 it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Gorm `.Updates()` don't update zero value of type ([Ref](http://gorm.io/docs/update.html))

```
// WARNING when update with struct, GORM will only update those fields that with non blank value
// For below Update, nothing will be updated as "", 0, false are blank values of their types
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "", Age: 0, Actived: false})
```

The zero value for `uint` is `0` but for the pointer of `uint`, it is `nil` that will not ignore `0` as blank value. You need to use pointer of `uint` then `FeaturedMediumID` will update as `0` in the database if you send `0`.

```
type Catalog struct {
    ...
    FeaturedMediumID *uint  `gorm:"column:featured_medium_id" json:"featured_medium_id" sql:"DEFAULT:NULL"`
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use [`null package`](https://github.com/guregu/null).

for example :

```
type Catalog struct {
    Title            string    `gorm:"column:title" json:"title"`
    Description      string    `gorm:"column:description" json:"description"`
    FeaturedMediumID null.Int      `gorm:"column:featured_medium_id" json:"featured_medium_id" sql:"DEFAULT:NULL"`
    FeaturedMedium   *Medium   `gorm:"foreignkey:featured_medium_id;association_foreignkey:id"  json:"featured_medium"`
    PublishedDate    time.Time `gorm:"column:published_date" json:"published_date"`
    Products         []Product `gorm:"many2many:catalog_product;" json:"products"`
}
```

then for set to null you must do this :

```
null.IntFromPtr(nil)
```

from your code, you must do this:

```
yourStruct := Catalog{}
yourStruct.FeaturedMediumID = null.IntFromPtr(nil)
```

then you can use `update`.